compose multiplatform apple sign in
I am currently working on implementing Apple Sign In using Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile (KMM) and Jetpack Compose Multiplatform. I have encountered an issue where the process gets stuck on the screen after the password input. Despite multiple attempts, I am not receiving any results or feedback in my logs, making it difficult to debug the problem.
Here are the specific steps I have taken so far:

I have set up the necessary configuration in the Apple Developer portal, including creating the App ID and enabling the appropriate capabilities.

I have integrated the required libraries and dependencies for Apple Sign In in my Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile project.

I have implemented the sign-in logic and ensured that the callback functions are in place to handle the response from Apple.


Despite these efforts, the application does not proceed past the password input screen, and no results or errors are logged. I suspect there might be an issue with how the callback functions are set up or possibly with the network permissions or entitlements.
Has anyone successfully implemented Apple Sign In using Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile and Jetpack Compose Multiplatform? If so, could you provide any insights or guidance on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
input password apple sign in
Here is what I did for my apple sign in
actual class AppleSignInManager actual constructor() {
    actual fun signIn(listener: AppleSignInListener) {
        val logger = Logger.withTag("AppleSignInManager")
        val provider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
        val request = provider.createRequest()
        request.requestedScopes = listOf(ASAuthorizationScopeFullName, ASAuthorizationScopeEmail)

        logger.i { "requestedScopes : ${ASAuthorizationScopeFullName.toString()} : ${ASAuthorizationScopeEmail.toString()} "}

        val controller = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests = listOf(request))
        val delegate = AuthorizationDelegate(listener, logger)
        controller.delegate = delegate
        controller.presentationContextProvider = delegate

        controller.performRequests()
    }
}

class AuthorizationDelegate(private val listener: AppleSignInListener, val logger: Logger) : NSObject(),
    ASAuthorizationControllerDelegateProtocol,
    ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProvidingProtocol {

    override fun authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization: ASAuthorization) {
        logger.i {"didCompleteWithAuthorization"}
        val credential = (didCompleteWithAuthorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential)
        val idTokenData = credential?.identityToken
        val idToken = idTokenData?.toUtf8String()
        if (idToken != null) {
            logger.i {didCompleteWithAuthorization.toString()}
            listener.onSignInSuccess(idToken)
        } else {
            logger.i {didCompleteWithAuthorization.toString()}
            listener.onSignInFailure(Throwable())
        }
    }

    override fun authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError: NSError) {
        logger.i {didCompleteWithError.localizedDescription}
        listener.onSignInFailure(Throwable())
    }

    override fun presentationAnchorForAuthorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController): UIWindow {
        return UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow!!
    }
}

fun NSData.toUtf8String(): String? {
    return NSString.create(data = this, encoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String?
}

Then I used it on button click
Button(onClick = { showContent = !showContent
                viewModel.saveToken(Config.ENVIRONMENT)
                viewModel.getToken()
                val appleSignIn = AppleSignInManager()
                appleSignIn.signIn(object : AppleSignInListener {
                    override fun onSignInSuccess(token: String) {
                        logger.i("Sign-in successful, ID token: $token")
                        // Handle success
                    }

                    override fun onSignInFailure(error: Throwable) {
                        logger.i("Sign-in failed, error: $error")
                        // Handle error
                    }
                })
            })


does this answer your question? Why does iOS delegate not work properly in KMM?

I'm not really sure, I also tried to create a new KMM and KMP and write the simple apple sign in directly in XCode still stack up on the same screen after input of password.

what have you tried after reading my answer?

@PhilDukhov I have solved the issue on the stack up screen it was not properly configure on part of bundle identifier but I'm still not receiving result after a successful sign in. What I did now is to write the Login UI in native code and do the rest in compose. Thank you good sir.

I mirrored my old Swift implementation (started building the app as Compose/Swift UI and recently switch to Compose MP) over into Kotlin and it works just as it did in Swift. I can share the code if you're interested but it's much the same as yours besides not requesting name scope and the code organisation is a bit different as I also support Apple login on Android via an Activity/Webview so I use the same entry point with expect/actuals.

@Philio can yo share the code kindly? i am also trying to implement apple login both on apple and android since 5 days but still stuck.

@AliAsjad just saw the notification, did you fix it? Which bit specifically were you after?

@Philio have implemented the google part but still stuck with Apple one.
